# Rails: How can I implement this relationship between these models? habtm? habtm through? Polymorphic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations, activemodel, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am storing my files on Amazon s3. Each file has many **"consumers"** and these consumers can be of any type(users, external apps, business_listings, etc). 
This calls for a many to many relationship. However, I also want to store certain attributes about each relationship. So I think that the best way to approach this would be to create a *has_and_belngs_to_many_through* relationship between the **"s3_files"** and the **consumers**

The question now is, since there are many type of consumers, I need to use polymorphic associations.

So based on this I would take the following steps:

```
1) Create a model: "resource_relationship"
2) Have these fields in it:
  t.string: consumer_type
  t.string: s3_fileType
  t.string: file_path
  t.string: consumer_type
  t.integer: s3_file.id
  t.integer: consumer.id
  t.integer: resource_relationship.id
 3) Add to the model:
     belongs_to: s3_file
     belongs_to: consumer
 4) add_index:[s3_file.id, consumer.id]

 5) Inside: s3_file
     nas_many: resource_relationships
     has_many:consumers :through=> :resource_relationships
 6) Inside: Users
     nas_many: resource_relationships
     has_many:s3_files :through=> :resource_relationships
 7) Inside: business_listings
     nas_many: resource_relationships
     has_many:s3_files :through=> :resource_relationships
```

My confusion lies in the polymorphic part of this relationship.

Since I donot have a "Consumer" model. I donot understand how that fits into this equation. I saw some tutorials online and came up with the above method and concept, but, Im uncertain if this si the correct way to approach this problem.

Essentially, I understand here that "Consumers" is like an interface that all the models "implement" and then the S3_file model can associate itself with any model that has "implemented" this interface. Question is how and where do the models: users and business_listings "implement" this "Consumer" interface. How do I set that up?

Comment: Each file can have many consumers -- but can each consumer have more than one file?

Comment: Yes, each consumer can have more than 1 file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want to store attributes *about* the relationship between to models in a many-to-many relationship, generally the relationship is **:has_many, :through**.

I'd recommend beginning with this simpler approach and then considering polymorphism later, if you need to. For now, begin with just having a `consumer_type` attribute you can use if you need it.

consumer.rb:

```
class Consumer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :resource_relationships
  has_many :s3_files, through: :resource_relationships
  validates_presence_of :consumer_type
end
```

resource_relationship.rb:

```
class ResourceRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :consumer
  belongs_to :s3_file
end
```

s3_file.rb

```
class S3File < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :resource_relationships
  has_many :consumers, through: :resource_relationships
  validates_presence_of :s3_fileType
  validates_presence_of :file_path
end
```

Notice that this simplifies as well the need to have attributes in the `resource_relationships` table -- those attributes are really attributes of the `consumer` and `s3_file` models anyway, so it may be best to just keep them there.

`:has_many, :through` I generally find to be more flexible and easier to modify as the relationships between your models changes.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. However, Im not sure I still understand how I would establish a connection between s3file and users, business_listings and other models? Do I need another many_toMany relationship between consumer and these models?